# Regular expression for youtube links

Tags: regex, youtube

Does someone have a regular expression that gets a link to a Youtube video (not embedded object) from (almost) all the possible ways of linking to Youtube?

I think this is a pretty common problem and I'm sure there are a lot of ways to link that.

A starting point would be:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related
- http://youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA
- http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA
- http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
- http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
- ... please add more possible links and/or regular expressions to detect them.

Comment: Did you forget "https://www.youtube.com/embed/UIpuNuV23v0"?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

So far I got this `Regular expression` working for the examples I posted, and it gets the ID on the first group:

```
http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?
```

Comment: I like that it matches the short links too!

Comment: I changed the identifier sub-pattern to require one or more characters, and to include the dash character: `([\w\-]+)`

Comment: @Sonny which part of the regular expression above is the identifier sub-pattern?

Comment: @yourfriendzak - `(\w*)` becomes `([\w\-]+)`. I have also allowed for SSL in my regex. This is the regular expression that I am currently using in PHP: `http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?`

Comment: I have just updated mine to handle URL parameters that precede video identifier: `#^http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?#i`

Comment: `\w*` doesn't cover all valid Youtube IDs, there can also be hyphen and underscore characters. `[\w\-\_]*` would be a suitable replacement. `/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/` should find all valid IDs. I had to change it to a literal to do a thing I was working on and can't remember which escapes I need. I could try to find them with regular expressions, but...

Comment: From the comments here the best one I have come up with now is `http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?‌​=]*)?`

Comment: From the comments above I added embed URLs as well ```http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/)|\.be\/)(?P<video_id>[\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?```

Comment: The regular expression has some invisible invalid characters when copy-pasted, you can see this from html-source or by copying it to text editor. Could the author correct this please? The edit is less than 6 characters.

Comment: If you are reading this, please be aware that @melbic 's solution only works on the PCRE RegEx engine, used with PHP and not the JavaScript engine.

Comment: This will give a runtime error `Unrecognized escape sequence \_` in C#

Comment: The original regex without invisible characters is this one `http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)[\w\=]*)?`

Answer (score 21):

You can use this expression below.

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?\/?.*(?:watch|embed)?(?:.*v=|v\/|\/)([\w\-_]+)\&?
```

I'm using it, and it cover the most used URLs.
I'll keep updating it on [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/927fd8feaaccdbb9d02b).
You can test it on this [tool](https://regex101.com/r/pO4dS6/1).

Answer (score 9):

I like @brunodles's solution the most but you can still match non video links like `https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions`

I went with this solution

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be\/|be.com\/\S*(?:watch|embed)(?:(?:(?=\/[-a-zA-Z0-9_]{11,}(?!\S))\/)|(?:\S*v=|v\/)))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]{11,})
```

It can also be used to match multiple whitespace separated links.
The video id will be captured in the first group.

Tested with the following urls:

```
youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA
youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoBL33GT9S8&feature=share
https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iwGFalTRHDA
https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
https://www.youtube.com/embed/v=iwGFalTRHDA
https://www.youtube.com/watch/iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?u=/watch?v=aGmiw_rrNxk&feature=share
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA

// will not match
https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgc00bfF_PvO_2AvqJZHXFg
https://www.youtube.com/c/NatGeoEdOrg/videos
```

https://regex101.com/r/rq2KLv/1

Answer (score 6):

I improved the links posted above with a friend for a script I wrote for IRC to recognize even links without http at all. It worked on all stress tests I got so far, including garbled text with barely recognizable youtube urls, so here it is:

```
~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?~
```

Comment: Not working in php: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/' in ...`

Answer (score 4):

I testet all the regular expressions that are shown here and none could cover all url types that my client was using.

I built this pretty much through trial and error, but it seems to work with all the patterns that Poppy Deejay posted.

```
"(?:.+?)?(?:\/v\/|watch\/|\?v=|\&v=|youtu\.be\/|\/v=|^youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})+"
```

Maybe it helps someone who is in a similar situation that I had today ;)

Answer (score 4):

Piggy backing on [Fanmade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3652125/fanmade), this covers the below links including the url encoded version of attribution_links:

```
(?:.+?)?(?:\/v\/|watch\/|\?v=|\&v=|youtu\.be\/|\/v=|^youtu\.be\/|watch\%3Fv\%3D)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})+



https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=tolCzpA7CrY&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DMoBL33GT9S8%26feature%3Dshare
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoBL33GT9S8&feature=share
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related 
http://youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA 
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
www.youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA 
youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA 
youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
http://www.youtube.com/watch/iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/v/iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/v/i_GFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-GFalTRHDA&feature=related 
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?u=/watch?v=aGmiw_rrNxk&feature=share&a=9QlmP1yvjcllp0h3l0NwuA
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=fF1CWYwxCQ4&u=/watch?v=qYr8opTPSaQ&feature=em-uploademail
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=fF1CWYwxCQ4&feature=em-uploademail&u=/watch?v=qYr8opTPSaQ
```

Comment: Hi all , this is the most correct / comprehensive solution. (2017/March)

Comment: It still has some flaw : it matches from the line start , for example , if the line is `OOXX http://www.youtube.com/v/iwGFalTRHDA` , the `OOXX ` part will be matched.

Comment: Oops , it can not handle list , ex : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrO4YZeyl0I&index=2&list=PL5F47FAD7E4D6276E` , it can grab the `v` value , but cannot match the whole URL.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having problems lately with the atttribution_link urls so i tried making my own regex that works for those too.

Here is my regex string:

```
(https?://)?(www\\.)?(yotu\\.be/|youtube\\.com/)?((.+/)?(watch(\\?v=|.+&v=))?(v=)?)([\\w_-]{11})(&.+)?
```

and here are some test cases i've tried:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related 
http://youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA 
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
www.youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA 
youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA 
youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA 
http://www.youtube.com/watch/iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/v/iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/v/i_GFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-GFalTRHDA&feature=related 
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?u=/watch?v=aGmiw_rrNxk&feature=share&a=9QlmP1yvjcllp0h3l0NwuA
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=fF1CWYwxCQ4&u=/watch?v=qYr8opTPSaQ&feature=em-uploademail
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=fF1CWYwxCQ4&feature=em-uploademail&u=/watch?v=qYr8opTPSaQ
```

Also remember to check the string you get for your video url, sometimes it may get the percent characters. If so just do this

```
url = [url stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and it should fix it.

Remember also that the index of the youtube key is now index 9.

```
NSRange youtubeKey = [result rangeAtIndex:9]; //the youtube key
NSString * strKey = [url substringWithRange:youtubeKey] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be the longest RegEx in the world if you managed to cover all link formats, but here's one to get you started which will cover the first couple of link formats:

```
http://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*
```

The second group will match the video ID if you need to get that out.

Comment: youtube id may contain dash (`-`), which above does not predict

Comment: It can also contain underscores

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:m.)?(?:music.)?youtu(?:\.?be)(?:\.com)?(?:(?:\w*.?:\/\/)?\w*.?\w*-?.?\w*\/(?:embed|e|v|watch|.*\/)?\??(?:feature=\w*\.?\w*)?&?(?:v=)?\/?)([\w\d_-]{11})(?:\S+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/nJzgG0/3

Detects YouTube and YouTube Music link in any string

Comment: `(?:s)?` is better written `s?` you must escape the dots. `(?:be|.be)?` ==> `(?:\.?be)?`. It matches `youtu/-----------`

Comment: `(?:\.?be)?` is also matches `youtu/-----------`. It will be more correct to use the `(?:\.?be)`. But you are right. Thank you) I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I took all variants from here:

https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486#file-youtubeurlformats-txt

And built this regexp (YouTube ID is in group 2):

```
(\/|%3D|v=|vi=)([0-9A-z-_]{11})[%#?&\s]
```

Check it here: https://regexr.com/4u4ud

Edit: Works for any single string w/o breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with that kind of links:

http://www.youtube.com/v/M-faNJWc9T0?fs=1&rel=0

And here's the regEx I'm using to get ID from it:

```
"(.+?)(\/v/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})+"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is iterating on the existing answers and handles edge cases better. (for example http://thisisnotyoutu.be/thing)

```
/(?:https?:\/\/|www\.|m\.|^)youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be\/)([\w‌​\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete solution for getting youtube video id for java or android, i didn't found any link which doesn't work with this function

```
public static String getValidYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl)
{
    if(youtubeUrl == null || youtubeUrl.trim().contentEquals(""))
    {
        return "";
    }
    youtubeUrl = youtubeUrl.trim();
    String validYoutubeVideoId = "";
    String regexPattern = "^(?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be\\/|youtube\\.com\\S*[^\\w\\-\\s])([\\w\\-]{11})(?=[^\\w\\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\\w]*(?:['\"][^<>]*>|<\\/a>))[?=&+%\\w]*";
    Pattern regexCompiled = Pattern.compile(regexPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regexCompiled.matcher(youtubeUrl);
    if(regexMatcher.find())
    {
        try
        {
            validYoutubeVideoId = regexMatcher.group(1);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    return validYoutubeVideoId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to use in Scala. This is useful to extract 11 digits from Youtube's URL.

> "https?://(?:[0-9a-zA-Z-]+.)?(?:www.youtube.com/|youtu.be\S*[^\w-\s])([\w -]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>|))[?=&+%\w-]*"

```
def getVideoLinkWR: UserDefinedFunction = udf(f = (videoLink: String) => {
    val youtubeRgx = """https?://(?:[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com\S*[^\w\-\s])([\w \-]{11})(?=[^\w\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>|</a>))[?=&+%\w-./]*""".r
    videoLink match {
        case youtubeRgx(a) => s"$a".toString
        case _ => videoLink.toString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube video URL Change to iframe supported link:

REGEX: https://regex101.com/r/LeZ9WH/2/

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related
http://youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA
http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
https://youtu.be/2sFlFPmUfNo?t=1
```

Php function example:

```
if (!function_exists('clean_youtube_link')) {

        /**
         * @param $link
         * @return string|string[]|null
         */
        function clean_youtube_link($link)
        {
            return preg_replace(
                '#(.+?)(\/)(watch\x3Fv=)?(embed\/watch\x3Ffeature\=player_embedded\x26v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})+#',
                "https://www.youtube.com/embed/$5",
                $link
            );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for almost all youtube links when extracting from a string:

```
((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]{10}).\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var isValidYoutubeLink: Bool{
        // working for all the youtube url's
        NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?:http?s?:\\/\\/)?(?:www.)?(?:m.)?(?:music.)?youtu(?:\\.?be)(?:\\.com)?(?:(?:\\w*.?:\\/\\/)?\\w*.?\\w*-?.?\\w*\\/(?:embed|e|v|watch|.*\\/)?\\??(?:feature=\\w*\\.?\\w*)?&?(?:v=)?\\/?)([\\w\\d_-]{11})(?:\\S+)?").evaluate(with: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this Javascript Regex, the first capture is a video ID :

`^(?:https?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.(?:[A-Za-z]{2,4}|[A-Za-z]{2,3}\.[A-Za-z]{2})\/)(?:watch|embed\/|vi?\/)*(?:\?[\w=&]*vi?=)?([^#&\?\/]{11}).*$`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?-s)^https?\W+(?:www\.|m\.|music\.)*youtu\.?be(?:\.com|\/watch|\/o?embed|\/shorts|\/attribution_link\?[&\w\-=]*[au]=|\/ytsc\w+|[\?&\/]+[ve]i?\b|\?feature=\w+|-nocookie)*[\/=]([a-z\d\-_]{11})[\?&#% \t ] *.*$
```

or

```
(?-s)^(?:(?!https?[:\/]|www\.|m\.yo|music\.yo|youtu\.?be[\/\.]|watch[\/\?]|embed\/)\V)*(?:https?[:\/]+|www\.|m\.|music\.)+youtu\.?be(?:\.com\/|watch|o?embed(?:\/|\?url=\S+?)?|shorts|attribution_link\?[&\w\-=]*[au]=\/?|ytsc\w+|[\?&]*[ve]i?\b|\?feature=\w+|[\?&]time_continue=\d+|-nocookie|%[23][56FD])*(?:[\/=]|%2F|%3D)([a-z\d\-_]{11})[\?&#% \t ]? *.*$
```

(the part >>#% \t⠀　]<< should contain continuous space, which is Alt+255, but stackoverflow-com can't print it)
(this string may be replaced to \1, sorted and abbreviated with: )

```
V█(?-i)^([A-Za-z\d\-_]{11})(?:\v+\1)*$
>█https:\/\/youtu\.be\/\1
```

(./dot can take up any symbol; \V or [^\r\n] can any except special, emoji and others; this >> [^!-⠀：／‽｜\s] << can grab some emoji)

```
https://youtu.be/x26ANNC3C-8 • ♾  -    • 7:15
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to cover all YouTube URL variants try this:

```
^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:shorts\/|live\/|v\/|e(?:mbed)?\/|watch(?:\/|\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v=)|oembed\?url=https?%3A\/\/(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v%3D|attribution_link\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*u=(?:\/|%2F)watch(?:\?|%3F)v(?:=|%3D))?|www\.youtube-nocookie\.com\/embed\/)([\w-]{11})[\?&#]?\S*$
```

It's a RegExp from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172756/11194000) for any known YouTube URL (also music.*, shorts/, live/, e/ embed/, v/, *-nocookie etc.). Also catches video ID.

If you want you can restrict the video ID further with [Glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988283/11194000) instead of `([\w-]{11})`.

Answer (score -1):

This regex solve my problem, I can get youtube link having watch, embed or shared link

```
(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'<> #]+)
```

You can check here https://regex101.com/r/Kvk0nB/1