# getting the youtube id from a link

Tags: java, regex, parsing, url, youtube

I got this code to get the youtube id from the links like 
www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx

```
  URL youtubeURL = new URL(link);
  youtubeURL.getQuery();
```

basically this will get me the id easily v=xxxxxxxx

but I noticed sometime youtube links will be like this

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xxxxxx
```

I am getting the links from a feed
so do I need to build a regex for that or theres a parser to get that for me ?

Comment: You may want to look at [my answer to a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string/5831191#5831191). It extracts the video-id from a variety of YouTube URL formats.

Comment: @ridgerunner thanks but it misses the gdata links

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updatated [my YouTube ID matching expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string/5831191#5831191) so that it now correctly matches your `gdata` subdomain example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Tried the other ones but failed in my case - adjusted the regex to fit for my urls

```
String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*";
    
    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);

    if(matcher.find()){
        return matcher.group();
    }
```

This one works for: (you could also implement a security check youtubeid length = 11 )

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/Woq5iX9XQhA?html5=1
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=384IUU43bfQ
>
> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xTmi7zzUa-M&whatever
>
> Woq5iX9XQhA
>
> 384IUU43bfQ
>
> xTmi7zzUa-M

Comment: it's not pretty, but here you go: ```(?<=watch\?v=|/videos/|embed\/|youtu.be\/|\/v\/|watch\?v%3D|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\&\?\n]*```

Answer (score 7):

```
public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl)
 {
 String video_id="";
  if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http"))
 {

String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"+ "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; // var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
 CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
 if (matcher.matches())
 {
String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
 if(groupIndex1!=null && groupIndex1.length()==11)
 video_id = groupIndex1;
 }
 }
 return video_id;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

This regex would do the trick:

```
(?<=videos\/|v=)([\w-]+)
```

This means that we're first looking for `video/` or `v=` then captures all the following characters that can be in word (letters, digits, and underscores) and hyphens.

Example in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String link = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xTmi7zzUa-M&whatever";
    String pattern = "(?:videos\\/|v=)([\\w-]+)";

    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(link);

    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
xTmi7zzUa-M
```

Comment: this will not get me the id only

Comment: Using `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xxxxxx` as indata I get `xTmi7zzUa-M` as output. Did I misread your question and you were asking for a regex that would allow you to parse both `v=xxxxxxxx` and the other one?

Comment: Well actually. That regex works in both cases. What result do you get?

Comment: but the regex you wrote will get me the id and other stuff
check here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: It's the '$' at the end that makes it only capture everything beyond .../videos/. It wouldn't work in the first example if there if there were any other parameters on the link (i.e. v=xxxxxxx&other_param=yyyyy...)

Comment: Salah have a look at my updated answer now. @Derek you're right about that, though that wasn't specified in the question I didn't take that into account.

Comment: A lookbehind would be better in certain cases than a non-capturing group. If used instead, the entire match (that is `matcher.group()`) would be the id the asker is looking for, rather than the first capturing group (`matcher.group(1)`)

Comment: @Jockey you're right about that. I replaced my non capturing group with a positive lookbehind. Ty

Answer (score 3):

Got a better solution from this [link](https://gist.github.com/jvanderwee/b30fdb496acff43aef8e).

Use the following method to get the videoId from the link.

> YoutubeHelper.java

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton; 

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Singleton 
public class YouTubeHelper { 

    final String youTubeUrlRegEx = "^(https?)?(://)?(www.)?(m.)?((youtube.com)|(youtu.be))/";
    final String[] videoIdRegex = { "\\?vi?=([^&]*)","watch\\?.*v=([^&]*)", "(?:embed|vi?)/([^/?]*)", "^([A-Za-z0-9\\-]*)"};

    public String extractVideoIdFromUrl(String url) {
        String youTubeLinkWithoutProtocolAndDomain = youTubeLinkWithoutProtocolAndDomain(url);

        for(String regex : videoIdRegex) {
            Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(youTubeLinkWithoutProtocolAndDomain);

            if(matcher.find()){
                return matcher.group(1);
            } 
        } 

        return null; 
    } 

    private String youTubeLinkWithoutProtocolAndDomain(String url) {
        Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(youTubeUrlRegEx);
        Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);

        if(matcher.find()){
            return url.replace(matcher.group(), "");
        } 
        return url;
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That pattern worked for me:

```
"http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=‌​]*)?"
```

source: [Regular expression for youtube links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the complete specification for all the possible YouTube URLs, this seems to work for the examples you provided:

```
//*EDIT* - fixed to hopefully support more recent youtube link styles/formats:
(?<=watch\?v=|/videos/|/embed/|youtu.be/)[^&#?]*
```

... matches `PjDw3azfZWI` from either of these URLS:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjDw3azfZWI#t=31m08s
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PjDw3azfZWI
```

You would need a little more to get that particular info if you did not know that these were from youtube, though that's a pretty quick check

Keep in mind that if you are trying to use only the result of the `getQuery()` method, it will not be possible to extract the result from the `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PjDw3azfZWI` URL, as this URL does not have a query part to it...

Java Example:

```
Pattern rex = Pattern.compile("(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/)[^&#]*");
Matcher m = rex.matcher(link);
String YouTubeVideoID = m.group();
```

Comment: @krishan indeed not (that wasn't even a valid URL when this question was asked, to my knowledge...) but if you're interested, this should work for the `youtu.be` as well as `/embed/` links: `(?<=watch\?v=|/videos/|/embed/|youtu.be/)[^&#?]*` (I'll update my answer) - please let me know if it doesn't, as I made that up just now by hand...

Comment: i got a solution about this my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718304/how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url-with-java/

Answer (score 1):

This was worked for me

```
public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl) {
    String videoId = "";
    if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http")) {

        String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"+ "/)" + "|(v/)|(/u/w/)|(embed/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#&\\?]*).*"; // var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(youtubeUrl);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if(groupIndex1!=null && groupIndex1.length()==11)
                videoId = groupIndex1;
        }

    }
    return videoId;
}
```

Source [link](https://androidsnippets.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/how-to-get-extract-video-id-from-an-youtube-url-in-android-java/)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use a regex but should still do the job.

```
/**
 * Returns the video id of a YouTube watch link.
 */
public static String getVideoId(String watchLink)
{
    return watchLink.substring(watchLink.length() - 11);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work me and simple

public static String getVideoId(@NonNull String videoUrl) {
    String reg = "(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\\.com\\/(?:[^\\/\\n\\s]+\\/\\S+\\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\\/|\\S*?[?&]v=)|youtu\\.be\\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(videoUrl);

    if (matcher.find())
        return matcher.group(1);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `kotlin` version that will support many of Youtube urls including ***Shorts***:

```
private fun getVideoId(youtubeUrl: String): String {
    var videoId = ""
    val regex = "/(?:watch|\\w+\\?(?:feature=\\w+.\\w+&)?v=|(videos/)|v/|e/|embed/|live/|shorts/|user/(?:[\\w#]+/)+)([^&#?\\n]+)"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(youtubeUrl)
    if(matcher.find()){
        videoId = matcher.group(2).orEmpty()
    }
    return videoId
}
```

Here are some samples to I've tested against:

```
https://youtube.com/watch?v=olij8GbEHJ0
www.youtube.com/watch?v=olij8GbEHJ0
https://youtu.be/shorts/fMlV1dGb1cI?feature=share
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xxxxxx
http://www.youtube.com/embed/Woq5iX9XQhA?html5=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=384IUU43bfQ
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xTmi7zzUa-M&whatever
```

Try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) choosing Java on the left menu