# Java regular expression is not matching valid results

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a simple java regular expression to extract out the video id of a given youtube video from its url. E.g for:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mzvAAuCo1c
```

I want to extract out: `-mzvAAuCo1c`.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v=([^&]+)");
String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mzvAAuCo1c";
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(url);
System.out.println(matcher.getGroupCount() ); //outputs 1
System.out.println(matcher.matches() ); //returns false;
System.out.println( matcher.group(0) ); //throws exception, same for 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did your code even compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to match the partial `String`. Dont call `matches` after calling `find` - this will result in an `IllegalStateException`. You want to capture group `1` rather than `0` as the latter returns the full `String`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v=([^&]+)");
String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mzvAAuCo1c&foo=3";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.groupCount()); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(url);
System.out.println(matcher.getGroupCount() ); //outputs 1
```

First, the two lines above do not even compile. Change them to:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
System.out.println(matcher.groupCount() ); //outputs 1
```

Second, your regular expression:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v=([^&]+)");
```

only matches part of the input, which is why

```
matcher.matches()
```

returns `false`. Change the regular expression to:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*v=([^&]+)");
```

Finally, since `matcher.matches()` does not return `true`, the statement

```
matcher.group(0)
```

will throw an exception.

Fixed code:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*v=([^&]+)");
        String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mzvAAuCo1c";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
        System.out.println(matcher.groupCount()); //outputs 1
        System.out.println(matcher.matches()); //returns true;
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //returns -mzvAAuCo1c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<=videos\/|v=)([\w-]+)
```

In use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String link = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xTmi7zzUa-M&whatever";
String pattern = "(?:videos\\/|v=)([\\w-]+)";

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(link);

if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730328/getting-the-youtube-id-from-a-link).