# Extract youtube channel id from channel url - android

Tags: android, regex, youtube, youtube-channels

Example URL : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw

I need only UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw (Channel ID)

Comment: remove `https://www.youtube.com/channel/` (obviously). What is a problem?

Comment: The url is from user input, so need to check the url as well.

Comment: then there are 2 separate tasks: 1) check the URL (whether it has `https://www.youtube.com/channel/`); 2) remove `https://www.youtube.com/channel/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern you can use to capture the channel id and this will validate the url also

```
 ^(?:(http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z-]*\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z-]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,})\/channel\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,})$
```

I have no idea how to execute regex in android but sharing the regex url, you can check from here https://regex101.com/r/9sjMPp/1

Or a javascript code to perform

```
var str = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw";
var pattern = /^(?:(http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z-]*\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z-]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,})\/channel\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,})$/;
var matchs = str.match(pattern);
console.log(matchs[2]);
// output is UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw
```

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Subhendu Mondal decision crashes on links like this.

```
// args after id

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw?view_as=subscriber 

//minus sign in id

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ18THOcZ8nIP-A3ZCqqZwA
```

so here is improved decision, also protocol group was removed from match result

```
^(?:http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z-]*\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z-]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,}\/channel\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{3,24})
```

```
var str = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw";
var pattern = /^(?:(http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z-]*\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z-]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,})\/channel\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,})$/;
var match = str.match(pattern);
console.log(match[1]);
```

*UPDATE:*

Here is the shortest way:

```
youtube.com\/channel\/([^#\&\?]*).*
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string into a URI:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw")
    String id = uri.lastPathSegment() //UCAoMPWcQKA_9Af5YhWdrZgw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for retrieving video ids from different types of youtube url.

```
String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";
```

Then generate a Pattern instance using the above regex, from which you can get a Matcher instance by using `Pattern.matcher(videoLink)`.
Now the `Matcher.find()` will give you a boolean on whether the above regex occurs in the given video link or not.
Depending on that you can use `Matcher.group()`, which will give you back the video id.

[Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31940028/3170451)