# Javascript replace using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need replace url from a string.

example:

```
var container = "hello http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r94hrE10S84 hello";
```

I want replace to:

```
container = "hello <iframe  src='//www.youtube.com/embed/r94hrE10S84' </iframe> guys";
```

Im trying to do:

```
container = container.replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=(/\w*\d+\w*/)","<iframe src='//www.youtube.com/embed/$1' </iframe>");
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
repl = container.replace(/(https?:\/\/\S+)/i, function(m) { 
        if (m.indexOf(".youtube."))
         return m.replace(/^(.+?)\/watch\?v=(.+)$/, "<iframe src='$1/embed/$2'> </iframe>");
       else return m;
    });

//=> ello <iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/r94hrE10S84'> </iframe> hello
```

Comment: Ty but it don't change watch?v= for embed/ and I only want change url of youtube.

Answer (score 1):

```
container.replace(/(https?:\/\/\S+)/i, "<iframe  src='$1' </iframe>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be/)([\w‌​\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?
```

ID Should be on first group.

So your code will be like:

```
var container = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r94hrE10S84";
var reg = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be\/)([\w‌​\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/;
container = container.replace(reg,"<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$1\"></iframe>");
```

This take into account even link w/o www, w/o protocol and short links (youtu.be)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoloft/p4UDp/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3726073/1446321)