# Convert Youtube Url to Video Flash Url Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, youtube

I am using Microsoft Web Helpers in my application and using

> @Video.Flash(path: "http://www.youtube.com/v/o3mP3mJDL2k", width:
>   "200", height: "200")

to embed a youtube url.

The actual url to the youtube video is

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3mP3mJDL2k

I was wondering if there is any utily or regex to convert the above url to the embed url format(/v/) ?

if other members are embedding videos in their website , i am curious to know how they are doing this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for youtube links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links)