# allow url youtube-nocookie in htmlpurifier

Tags: php, regex, htmlpurifier

I'm using to configure htmlpurifier at my system. i can authorize youtube iframes, but when i put a youtube-nocookie url, it is purified. the code above is whats i am doing. help me please? 
here is the code.

```
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?(\/\/www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/embed\/)%');
```

can u help me please?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "purified"?

Comment: @Tom purified is deleted, when i put an iframe without "https://www.youtube.com/embed" url, it is deleted. the thing is: i need to accept both "youtube.com" and "youtube-nocookie.com". understood?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041062/how-to-validate-the-youtube-embedded-link-only-using-regular-expression . The regex they use there goes like this: `\/\/www.youtube(?:-nocookie)?.com\/(?:v|embed)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).*`