# How to extract youtube url from string in Typescript

Tags: string, url, typescript, youtube

I have a text like

```
string 1 : 
I am a text and this is a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j82FBbgpUy4 !!!
```

I would like to extract the youtube video url from the string and return it.

Result :

```
string 2 :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j82FBbgpUy4
```

Is there another way more efficient than spliting the string by spaces and searching in the array if it contains "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" (it's not the best way to do it)? I cannot find any other solution

Comment: Your approach sounds acceptable to me. Unless there are extra nitpicky requirements, it should work fine. Optimize later if you deem it necessary.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript) if you want a regex based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. I found this regular expression `http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links), which seems to work.

Once you have that, all you have to do is this:

```
var re = /http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?/;
var str = "I am a text and this is a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j82FBbgpUy4 !!!"
var url = re.exec(str)['0']
```

Then `url` should have the video url.

Comment: This regular expression covers a bit more than the example URL you gave though. You can just find/make one that covers only the URLs you want to match though if you need to restrict it to the format you gave.

Comment: There is a problem with `var url = re.exec(str)['0']`, it returns error  `Error :TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null(…)` if `str` doesn't contain any valide url, I can't find how to solve it

Comment: Just check if it's null first. Just have an if checking `re.exec(str) == null` if it's true, then it's not there.