# Replacing youtube links with iframe in the html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript code that searches in a html page/content and replaces every youtube link with an iframe embedded link.

This works fine for normal youtube links like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xZL3WoBQzI
```

However, some of the video links in my html have an extra variable at the end of them which causes my JavaScript code to not work properly.

They are like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xZL3WoBQzI&t=15s
```

The issue is because of the `&t=15s`

This is my code:

```
$('.element').html(function(i, html) {

return html.replace(/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could adjust the regex to only look for word characters that come after the `v=`.

Your new regex would look like this: `/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?.*v=)?(\w+)/g`

The last bit changed from: `(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)` to `(?:watch\?.*v=)?(\w+)`

So your new code would look like:

```
$('.element').html(function(i, html) {

return html.replace(/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?.*v=)?(\w+)/g, '<iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});
```

**EDIT**: Dang it! As you can tell, coming up with the right regex takes time, so perhaps you should re-use the regex suggested here: [Regular expression for youtube links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links)

Hope this does the job :)

Comment: This breaks the code for normal YouTube links without the &t=15s

Comment: Oups, forgot to add ? after the non-capturing group `(?:&)?` Edited comment.

Comment: Now, it works with the normal links again but not for the links with the &t=15s variable.

Comment: Completely edited the reply with a solution that works for both and doesn't place a dependency on the order of the URL params

Comment: sorry but still not working! some of the youtube links in the html content look like this: https://youtu.be/Gx-x7_htyddf. my own code works fine with these links but with your code seems to ignore them as a valid youtube link and it doesn't create the iFrame for them!

Comment: Dang it, you're right ... how about the regex suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links ?

Comment: nice find. this regex seems to work fine: http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?

Comment: @RoozFar I'm glad things worked out :) Can you please close the question if it's been answered?