# PHP find youtube url to embed _match and _replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Unable to figure out why the following code doesn't work.

It takes text file content (string), replaces the youtube url (from the string) then embed it to other string, but I am getting no response.

```
// regex
$yt_pre = "/https?:\/\/(?:www)?\.youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/watch(?:\?(.*?)&|\?)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)/i";

// find
preg_match($yt_pre, $text, $yt_find);
$yt_loc = $yt_find[1];

// embed
$yt_rep = "<div class='youtube'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $yt_loc . "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen class='youtube_iframe'></iframe></div>";

// replace
preg_replace($yt_pre, $yt_rep, $text);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but I get no response"? What is the content of `$text`? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: @Toto The $text file has text with some html tags and links. It's used to fill a page by get_file_content etc. I am trying to convert the youtube links in the text to embed code. When I check for warnings or source .. I get no change at all from the code above. No alerts, not warnings, nothing.

Comment: Show us an extract of the input file and expected result.

Comment: added more clarity code

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might work for youtube links, which I have assumed that we'd have an ID with this pattern (`([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})`):

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be)?(?:\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/watch\?feature=player_embedded&v=)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})(.+)?
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0lKjHu/1/)

```
$re = '/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be)?(?:\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/watch\?feature=player_embedded&v=)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})(.+)?/m';
$str = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related
http://youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA
http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links)